# How to calculate the running sum of a data frame that has default values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum

I will have two data frames `a` and `b` and I want `a` to turn into a running sum of `b` given `a's` default values.

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> a
    a  b  c
 0  0  0  1
 1  0  0  0
 2  0  0  0
>>> b = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 2]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> b
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  4
2  4  5  2
```

My desired output is:

```
    a  b  c
0   1  2  4
1   2  4  8
2   6  9  10
```

I tried `a = b.cumsum()` but I get:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  4  7
2  6  9  9
```

Comment: Not last column have values `4,8,10` ?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) for sum values of both `DataFrame`s with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
print (b.add(a).cumsum())
   a  b   c
0  1  2   4
1  2  4   8
2  6  9  10
```

Detail:

```
print (b.add(a))
   a  b  c
0  1  2  4
1  1  2  4
2  4  5  2
```